# Intersecting dynamic bodies Box2D/Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Is that normal that while I'm jumping (by a player represented with a circle) on a dynamic bodies (boxes) they are interecting? It seems that there is some kind of diffraction. Is that any way to reduce this? Restitution is set to 0 for all.

The moment caught on a screenshot

[image: The moment caught on a screenshot]

And the moment after a collison

[image: the moment after a collison]

Answer (score 1):

A little overlap is to be expectedone with **Box2D**, try increasing the `positionIterations` parameter in the call to `World.step` (also consider experimenting with the `velocityIterations` parameter).

Increasing these values gives a more stable simulation with less collision overlap, but it comes at a performance cost.

You can also try stepping the `World` in smaller increments, [Gaffer on Games's Fix Your Timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) has a good description on how to decouple the physics time from the render time.

Play around with the values and find the compromise that works best for you.